# What is Action result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As per my understanding it is a class that can return a View
because on the basis of some action I am trying to execute a View.

Please confirm it s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
Encapsulates the result of an action method and is used to perform a framework-level operation on behalf of the action method.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 4):

`ActionResult` is base class for various results, that can be returned from an action method. It does not have to be necessarilly a view. There are plenty of options what an action result could be:

- `ContentResult` - user defined content
- `EmptyResult` - just empty
- `FileResult` - binary file
- `HttpStatusCodeResult` - specific HTTP response status code and description
- `JavaScriptResult` - js code
- `JsonResult` - data formated as JSON
- `RedirectResult` - redirect to url
- `RedirectToRouteResult` - redirect to some MVC route
- `ViewResult` - this is actually the view
- `PartialView` - partial view

The reason why you see it in most examples as return value from an action is that you could have:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if(someCondition)
       return View();  // return the view from action
    else
       return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction","OnSomeOtherController"); // redirect to other action 
}
```